# Using tailwind css or just vanilla css how can i create a radiating effect on a menubar?

Tags: css, animation

I have a simple menu that is closed and opened using state in react.

```
        <div className="fixed right-0 top-0 bg-primaryOrange text-white flex flex-col h-[50vh] z-50 w-[25vw] rounded-bl-full items-center justify-center gap-y-2 transition-all menu">
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faXmark}
            className="h-5 w-5 absolute top-5 right-5 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => setIsShowingMenu(false)}
          />
          <a
            href="/shop"
            className="hover:border-b border-white hover:pb-1 transition-all"
          >
            shop
          </a>
          <a
            href="/"
            className="hover:border-b border-white hover:pb-1 transition-all"
          >
            home
          </a>
        </div>
```

The menu is fine but i want it to have a sort of animation when it is shown. You might notic the `top-0 right-0` classes. That is where i want the menu to kind of radiate from. I also want it to recede to the top-right corner when unmounted

I tried adding this to the class but it didnt work as expected.

```
@keyframes radiate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.menu {
   animation: radiate 300ms ease
}
```

How can i achieve that effect. im open to using framer-motion if its necessary.

[image: screenshot of the menu]

Comment: Can you make a runnable snippet of what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate based upon  your code

#### Might work for you

```js
let menu_pane=document.querySelector('.menu');

    document.querySelector('button[name="menu"]').onclick=function(){
       menu_pane.classList.toggle('active');
    }

    document.querySelector('#close_btn').onclick=function(){
       menu_pane.classList.toggle('active');
    }
```

```css
    *
    {
        font-family: 'arial';
    }
.menu
{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
background: #EB3305;
color: white;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height:450px;
width: 450px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
transition: 0.4s;
transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
}
.menu a
{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

}

#close_btn
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.active
{
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button name="menu">MENU</button>
<div class="menu">
<a href="#/" id="close_btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
<a href="#/">Shop</a>
<a href="#/">Home</a>
</div>
```